# How to verify that all the drop down items in 'n' number of combo boxes are clickable?

Tags: robotframework

I have a web page in which there are 'n' number of combo boxes in a column. In which I have to verify that all the drop down items in each and every combo boxes are clickable in iteration using robot framework. I have my script as follows:

```
*** Keywords ***
User should be able to select each and every role suggested in the combo boxes
  @{combo_boxes}=  Get WebElements  css=div.col > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
  :FOR  ${each}  IN  @{combo_boxes}
  \  Click Element  ${each}
  \  Select drop down item

Select drop down item
  @{drop_down_list}=   Get WebElements  css=div.col:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{drop_down_list}
  \  Click Element  ${each}
```

On executing the above script we are getting the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <div _ngcontent-c6="" id="divCombo" style="height: 100%; background-color: transparent;">...</div> is not clickable at point (1014, 358). Other element would receive the click: <span _ngcontent-c6="" class="flexColumnFill dropdown-optionName">...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.77)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.544315 (730aa6a5fdba159ac9f4c1e8cbc59bf1b5ce12b7),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

[image: Sample image "'n' number of combo boxes in a column"]

Comment: Have you tried to first scroll it into view before clicking on it? This is a new keyword the SeleniumLibrary v3.2.0: [Scroll Element Into View](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Scroll%20Element%20Into%20View)

Comment: @A.Kootstra Can this scenario be executed in a nested for loop? Is there any flaws in the script executing nested for loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Loop
  @{combo_boxes}=  Get WebElements  css=.list > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child   (3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)
  ${INTEGER} =    Set Variable  2
  Set Suite Variable  ${INTEGER_A}  ${INTEGER}
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{combo_boxes}
  \  Click Element  ${each}
  \  ${roles_list}=  Set Variable    css=.list > div:nth-child(${INTEGER_A}) >  div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > combo-box:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div
  \  Loop A  ${roles_list}  ${each}
  \  ${INTEGER_A}=  Evaluate    ${INTEGER_A} + 1
  \  Sleep  0.5s
  \  Click Element  ${each}


Loop A
  [Arguments]  ${roles_list}  ${combo}
  @{get_role_list}=  Get WebElements  ${roles_list}
  :FOR    ${each}     IN      @{get_role_list}
  \    Click Element "${each}"
  \    Run Keyword If  '${each}'!='EXIT'  Click Element  ${combo}
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the screenshot, the failure comes from clicking the dropdown item in the column, not in clicking the individual items in it - right?

If so, that's because the items are obscuring the next dropdown - when the loop finishes, selenium tries to click the next dropdown, but the list of items is visible and above it, "getting in the way".
Upon finishing the individual items, just click somewhere else - in a blank spot if there page, and the list will disappear, thus allowing the next dropdown control to be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

In the below example a list of select boxes is fetched and then looped over to validate the menu's items. Granted, there is only one box on the page but the logic works if there were more.

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary    

Suite Teardown    Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
TC
    Open Browser    http://bootstrapformhelpers.com/select/   Chrome
    Maximize Browser Window

    Validate Dropdowns

*** Keywords ***
Validate Dropdowns
  @{drop_downs}=  Get WebElements  xpath://div[@data-name="selectbox1"]

  :FOR  ${each}  IN  @{drop_downs}
  \  Element Should Be Enabled    ${each}
  \  Click Element    ${each}
  \  
  \  ${name}    Get Element Attribute    ${each}     data-name
  \  Validate Dropdown Menu Items  ${name}  


Validate Dropdown Menu Items
  [Arguments]    ${dropdownname}
  @{menu_items}=  Get WebElements  xpath://div[@data-name="${dropdownname}"]//a

  :FOR  ${each}  IN  @{menu_items}
  \  Set Focus To Element    ${each}
  \  Sleep     0.2s    # Only for demo purpose.
  \  Element Should Be Visible    ${each}
  \  Element Should Be Enabled    ${each}
```